# Certificate-based authentication for users via a shared public key

Tags: authentication, certificates

I would like to authenticate my users to SalesForce (web console and Salesforce1 app) using client certificate based authentication (CBA) issued from my internal CA and eventually block username/password authentication.

We use an MDM solution to mange devices, so are able to distribute client certificates to desktops and mobile devices no problem.  From the Mobile App Security Guide chapter 7 (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce1_mobile_security.pdf) it seems straightforward enough to get client certificates to the Salesforce1 app on mobile, and users already have certs on their desktops via Group Policy.

The piece that I'm struggling with is how you configure the Salesforce service to trust the client certificates you've distributed to users.  In other systems that support CBA you would upload your issuing CA's public key to the service so it knows which client certificates it can trust and you might also tell it where in the client certificate to find the username (a SAN field for example).  However looking at the Salesforce documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_certificate_based_auth_upload.htm&type=5) it looks to me like you need to manually associate client certificates with each user individually.  This would actually be quite handy if you just wanted to authenticate a handful of users using CBA as it's quick and easy to do, but it would not be practical for a 1000 user site where client certificates and users will be changing on a daily basis.

Is there something I'm missing perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not missing anything.  It can be argued that in a lowest common denominator implementation that needs to address all kinds of customer scenarios, schemes such a shared public key + rules for traversing X.509 are too specific. For now you'll have to provision individual certs in SF.

Comment: OK thanks.  It's a strange implementation of certificate based authentication, first time I've seen it done this way in an enterprise-targetting solution.  Thanks again.